# /bin/sh: 1: cross-env: not found when i using github actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-actions

I want build the project with github actions. but I got an error, at step "build-for-devtools". workflow and error as below.

**workflow:**

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - name: setup node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2.1.5
        with:
          node-version: 14
          
      - name: install yarn
        run: sudo npm install -g yarn
      
      - name: clone source code
        run: |
          git clone https://github.com/facebook/react.git
          yarn install
          
      - name: build-for-devtools
        run: |
          cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/react
          pwd
          yarn build-for-devtools
```

**error:**

```
Run cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/react
/home/runner/work/react-dev-tool-build/react-dev-tool-build/react
yarn run v1.22.10
$ cross-env RELEASE_CHANNEL=experimental yarn build react/index,react-dom,react-is,react-debug-tools,scheduler,react-test-renderer,react-refresh --type=NODE && rm -rf build2 && mkdir build2 && cp -r ./build/node_modules build2/oss-experimental/
/bin/sh: 1: cross-env: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `cd react` before `yarn install` because git clones the repository to `./react`.

Comment: oh, a rookie mistake. Thanks a lot.